# PHP. It appears my variable not recognised in whole scope. Why not?

Tags: php

Can someone please tell me how I can get my `$cat_id` variable recognised in the ***SECOND PART*** of my code ? It works fine in the ***FIRST PART*** - I mean the `$cat_id` value is inserted into mysql database with :

```
$insert_review_command = "INSERT INTO review VALUES(NULL,'$cat_id','{$category}','$user_id', '{$name}','{$phonenumber}','{$address}', '{$comment}')";
```

But nothing inserts in the SECOND PART. I don't think my `$cat_id` is recognised. But why shouldn't it be ?Should `$cat_id` not be recognised throughout my whole code ? If it is defined within an `If statement` is it only recognised within that `If statement`? Thanks for any help.

```
<?php require('dbConnect.php'); 

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

    $category = ($_POST['category']);
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $phonenumber = ($_POST['phonenumber']);
    $address = ($_POST['address']);
    $comment = ($_POST['comment']);
    //check if the category being entered is already there
    $select_from_cat_table = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_name = '$_POST[category]'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_cat_table);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // get the matching cat_id 
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       $cat_id = $row["cat_id"];

//     ****FIRST PART****    $CAT_ID IS INSERTED INTO THE DB

//if the category name already exists in the category table, then don't add it in again
    if($num_rows >= 1) {
    echo "This Already Exists<br/>";
    //but do add it to the review table
    //for the cat_id, we want to get the cat_id of the category name that already exists, that has 
    //just been posted. This is $cat_id. $user_id is the user id of the person posting
    $insert_review_command = "INSERT INTO review VALUES(NULL,'$cat_id','{$category}','$user_id', '{$name}','{$phonenumber}','{$address}', '{$comment}')";
    $insert_into_review_table = mysqli_query($con,$insert_review_command);

}

//     ****SECOND PART****    $CAT_ID IS NOT INSERTED INTO THE DB
else if ($num_rows < 1) 

{
    //if it's not in there, then add the category in the category table.
    $insert_category_command = "INSERT INTO category VALUES(NULL, '{$category}', '$user_id')";
    $insert_into_category_table = mysqli_query($con,$insert_category_command);

    //****WHY IS CAT_ID NOT WORKING HERE????******

    //and add it to the review table
    //for the cat_id, we want to get the cat_id of the category name that already exists, that has 
    //just been posted. This is $cat_id. $user_id is the user id of the person posting
    $insert_review_command = "INSERT INTO review VALUES(NULL,'$cat_id','{$category}','$user_id', '{$name}','{$phonenumber}','{$address}', '{$comment}')";
    $insert_into_review_table = mysqli_query($con,$insert_review_command);

echo "Yes, it's been added correctly";
echo $cat_id;


}


$con->close();
header('Location:volleyLogin.php');
}



?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>Create new Contact</h2>
    <form method="post" action="" name="frmAdd">
    <p><input type="text" name = "category" id = "category" placeholder = "category"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name = "name" id = "name" placeholder = "name"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name = "phonenumber" id = "phonenumber" placeholder = "phone number"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name = "address" id = "address" placeholder = "address"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name = "comment" id = "comment" placeholder = "comment"></p>
    <h2>Visible to :</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="allmycontacts" value="All my Contacts">All my Contacts
    <input type="radio" name="selectwho" value="Select Who">Select Who
    <input type="radio" name="public" value="Public">Public
    <input type="radio" name="justme" value="Just me">Just me

    <p><input type="submit" name = "create" id = "create" value = "Create new Contact"></p>
    <a href="exit.php">Exit</a>

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Because if `($num_rows < 1)` returns true, then `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` didn't return anything. And you get `$cat_id` from the database, so if there aren't any rows to fetch, it can't have a value either.

Comment: After `$insert_into_category_table = ...`, *but before* `$insert_review_command =...`,   use `$cat_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);` to get the just inserted category id. see [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: Also, "SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_name = '$_POST[category]'"; could be "SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_name = '$category'";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is split into two parts, if `$num_rows` is greater than 0, or if it's 0. This is the result of a query, obviously. So when you do

```
$cat_id = $row["cat_id"];
```

from the first query, and `$num_rows` is zero, your `$cat_id` doesn't hold any values, because `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returned no rows (`mysqli_num_rows()` is 0), so `$row` is `null`.

Your solution is to fetch the recent inserted ID from your `category` table before you insert it into your `review` table.

Simply add

```
$cat_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

before your insert-query for the `review` table (but after you insert values into the `category` table).